# What does this command execute? - awk '{if ($2 ~ "variable1=") {split($2,res,"="); print res[2]}}

Tags: command-line, awk, split

What does this command execute on a linux based system? i.e. shell script

```
awk '{if ($2 ~ "variable1=") {split($2,res,"="); print res[2]}}
```

Comment: That is not all to it :P Basically it splits $2 and prints the 2nd part of $2 if $2 is like "variable1="

Comment: Lol you caught me :P but what's the diff between "=" and "~"

Comment: ~  is pattern matching ;)  see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the help and the website its useful info. Cheers!